# CSS making an image header in the foreground without HTML

Tags: css

What I want to achieve:

[image: What I want to achieve]

I am doing the very familiar CSS zen garden however I can't seem to get the image to float like this. I want it at the top of the page and to stay at the top like a toolbar like stackoverflow has mounted to the top of the page.

Unfortunately, any time I try to display my image it is not only behind the text but also far too large. I only see about 1/3rd of my image. If I try to scale it in any way then it disappears completely. I have seen that other people do this with the added `<divs>` but I am told that I should use `::before` to do this ....either way I can't get either to even display my image ...the only thing that does barely work is ...

```
body{
     background: url("../CSSMidterm/Header.png") center;
}
```

but as I said that displays 1/3rd of the image....any idea how I can rectify this situation?

To make it clear, I am asking how to **mount an image to the top of a webpage using ONLY CSS no touching HTML at all**. I want it to be fairly similar to the toolbar at the top of Stack Overflow own page.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```css
body {
  background : transparent url("../CSSMidterm/Header.png") no-repeat center center/cover;
}
```

[Link to the documentation for background css](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/background)

Comment: this is the closest it's ever been to looking acceptable but it still displays behind the text and the top part is cut off....could I do this with the ::before? could I put it in the head without it making my image all skinny? how can I add padding to the image?

Comment: I've made some progress with the size. unfortunately it seems like I can only add images with the background command...I still cannot get that image over text effect ...that is my biggest issue.

Comment: You need to do something like this

```css
html::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: transparent url("../CSSMidterm/Header.png") no-repeat bottom center/contain;
}
```